# J2EE / JSP Control Flow Issue

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm rather new to J2EE (though not to Java) and I have a question, I'd like to bounce off of some of you gurus.  I have read a number of tutorials but I'm still a bit hazy.  Here is the situation.

I've inherited a jsp which generates an html representation of some data stored in a database.  I need to modify it such that, if a certain request parameter is passed, in addition to generating the html representation, it will also generate an alternative representation (in pdf) of the data which it will return to the user via a post to a url which will also be specified in a request parameter.  So, what I want to do (when these two extra parameters are specified) is first return the HTML representation and then call a separate jsp / servlet which will be responsible for generating the PDF view and posting it back to the client.

My confusion is how to pass control from the initial jsp to my new jsp in such a way that the first jsp won't be blocked on the additional processing and the client will receive the HTML view even as the PDF stuff is cooking.  Does this make any sense?

My plan at the moment is to check the parameter in a scriptlet at the very bottom of the jsp and if it's 'true', to use apache HttpClient to post the request to the jsp / servlet (running in the same web app) responsible for generating the PDF.  That servlet will then use HttpClient to post the finished product back to the client.  I have no idea though if this is really the right way to do this or even if it will work, which is why I'm posting this question.  Any comments or suggestions would really be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Think it would be better to generate just the HTML output and place a link to your second Servlet, which generates PDF, somewhere in your output. This way, if user really wants to retrieve the PDF version, can click on the link provided and retrieve the PDF.

If your requirement is to generate the PDF when user tries to retrieve the HTML version, it would be nice to place a request in a JMS queue which generates an appropriate result in PDF version and stores them in a temporary location. When user clicks on download link for PDF version, you just need to fetch the result (generated through JMS) and send it back as result.

Comment: Hi moghaddam.  Thanks for taking the time to reply.  We actually did discuss including a link as you suggest but the other parties didn't want to do that.  The client here isn't actually an end user at a browswer, but rather a different java web application and the deal is that if the flag is passed they will need the pdf for sure.  The JMS idea is interesting, but this is just a small enhancement to an already existing and large web application and I don't think that adding a new technology is going to fly :)

Comment: I Got confused. You want to have a scriptlet at the end of your result page which sends another request to a servlet/jsp which generates the PDF. Let me know, how do you want to place the output of the second servlet inside your result page? The PDF output is a binary data and if you have to place it somewhere inside your result page, you have to have a common protocol with client application to extract the result from result page body. It could be something like a hidden tag which contains Base64 representation of the PDF file. You think I've understood your problem correctly? ;)

Comment: Hi again.  NO doubt you were confused because my post wasn't clear.  In any event, what I would like is for the PDF *not* to be included in the result page but rather to be returned in separate post operation initiated by my servlet.  So, in my scenario there would be potentially, based on the flag passed by the client three requests:

Comment: (1) the initial request that the client makes on my jsp that generate the html, (2) the request that my jsp would make on a different servlet running in my web app that would be responsible for generating the pdf and then (3) a request initiated by that servlet to send the results back to the client application.  The thing that makes me think that this isn't going to work is that I *don't* want the jsp to have to wait for the pdf generation to finish.  I want it to return the html to the client immediately after it's made the post on the pdf generating servlet.

Comment: So you have to have some sort of asynchronous method call, which could be achieved through JMS or another Thread. Any method call in your initial jsp page, would be blocking and it has to wait till the request completes